# pandas fill missing country values based on city if it exists

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to fill country names in my dataframe if it is null based on city and  country names, which exists. For eg see the dataframe below, here i want to replace NaN for City Bangalore with Country India if such City exists in the dataframe

```
df1=
         City Country
0   Bangalore   India
1       Delhi   India
2      London      UK
3  California     USA
4       Dubai     UAE
5   Abu Dhabi     UAE
6   Bangalore     NaN
```

I am new to this so any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: groupby and fillna

Comment: Use `df.groupby('City').Country.ffill()` or `df.groupby('City').Country.transform('first')`

Comment: What have you tried already, what are the results of your research so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a series mapping after dropping nulls and duplicates.

Then use `fillna` with `pd.Series.map`:

```
g = df.dropna(subset=['Country']).drop_duplicates('City').set_index('City')['Country']
df['Country'] = df['Country'].fillna(df['City'].map(g))

print(df)

         City Country
0   Bangalore   India
1       Delhi   India
2      London      UK
3  California     USA
4       Dubai     UAE
5    AbuDhabi     UAE
6   Bangalore   India
```

This solution will also work if `NaN` occurs first within a group.

Comment: Thanks alot this is what exactly i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
df1.groupby('City')['Country'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

should resolve your issue by forward filling missing values within the group by.

Comment: What if `NaN` occurs first?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways could be -

non_null_cities = df1.dropna().drop_duplicates(['City']).rename(columns={'Country':'C'}) 
df1 = df1.merge(non_null_cities, on='City', how='left') 
df1.loc[df1['Country'].isnull(), 'Country'] = df1['C'] 
del df1['C']

Hope this will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one nasty way to do it.

first use forward fill and then use backwardfill ( for the possible NaN occurs first)

```
df = df.groupby('City')[['City','Country']].fillna(method = 'ffill').groupby('City')[['City','Country']].fillna(method = 'bfill')
```